# Rails Xeroizer Contact Group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xero-api

I have this record as an example.
How do I use the API to retrieve all contacts in the insurance group?

```
ins = xero.Contact.find("3034b40e-ddd5-45b4-b23c-0f6800029673")
```

Contains:

> Xeroizer::Record::ContactGroup :contact_group_id: "0c72ed99-2c7d-482f-8c82-f53e268d20e0", :name: "insurance", :status: "ACTIVE"

and adding a contact to the group

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all the contacts in the insurance group,

```
ins = xero.ContactGroup.find('3034b40e-ddd5-45b4-b23c-0f6800029673').contacts
```

Comment: You really mean: ins = xero.ContactGroup.find('0c72ed99-2c7d-482f-8c82-f53e268d20e0').contacts     but how do I add "insurance" group to a contact through xeroizer?

Comment: Creating a contact inside a contact group was not possible through API. So I just created them through the UI. But I was able to retrieve them with the code I specified above.